# Python SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to build a program that tells you the monthly payments a person has to make for a loan
heres my code:

`

```
loan_amount = 650000
annual_interest_rate = 5
loan_length_years = 20
months_per_year = 12
i=annual_interest_rate/12
n=20*12
amt=loan_amount(i/100(1+i/100)**n)/(((1+i/100)**n)-1)
print('You will need to pay $',amt,'monthly.')
```

Comment: The expression for `amt` makes no sense - you have `loan_amount(...)` where `loan_amount` is a number, and `100(...)`, both of which look like function calls.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit multiplication of adjacent terms is a thing in mathematics, but not programming. Assuming the marked code was intended to be multiplication, then:

```
amt=loan_amount(i/100(1+i/100)**n)/(((1+i/100)**n)-1)
#             ^^    ^^
```

needs to be changed to:

```
amt=loan_amount*(i/100*(1+i/100)**n)/(((1+i/100)**n)-1)
#             ^^^    ^^^
```

The `SyntaxWarning` is specifically for the second problem (it's a `SyntaxWarning` because the inappropriateness of calling an `int` literal is identifiable at compile-time, while the fact that `loan_amount` is numeric, rather than a function, can't be proven at compile-time with Python's limited parsing facilities).

Comment: `loan_amount` is also a number so the code needs to be changed to `amt=loan_mount * (...`.

Comment: @I'mAUserNow: Good catch. Updated. The first fix I made was the one the `SyntaxWarning` was identifying (it can only identify the problem when a literal is involved, not a variable), but both of them would be a problem at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Python is not Mathematica, and you cannot omit operators. You need to add asterisks back to the expression.

```py
amt=loan_amount*(i/100*(1+i/100)**n)/(((1+i/100)**n)-1)
```

Moreover, an object directly followed by a pair of brackets indicates a *function call*. For example, `print()`, `sqrt()`, `str()` and so on. In your code, Python is trying to interpret `loan_amount` as a funcion, but actually it's an integer. That's the reason why it raises `SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable`.

Comment: To be clear, the `SyntaxWarning` comes from the `100(...)`, not the `loan_amount(...)`. Python's parser has no idea what `loan_amount` is (it could hold anything), but it knows with 100% certainty that `100` is an `int`, and they the subsequent parens are trying to call it like a function, so it's possible to issue the warning there. The `loan_amount(...)` would fail at *runtime*, but the parser won't see any problems.